# What is uppercase ${\cal O}$ in electrodynamics?

Tags: notation

I'm a bit puzzled as to what the symbol ${\cal O}$ means in electrodynamics, I'm reading this paper here http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0404512.
See equation 43 which is in page 12, what is this uppercase ${\cal O}$? I can't find its definition anywhere.

Comment: This is [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: @lemon I've never seen it before, does it have a specific value?

Comment: Is it possible to omit it from my calculations or is it really important? because I have no idea how to treat it when taking derivatives or plotting a function that has Big O in it

Comment: It's not a value or a function, but rather a shorthand for describing limiting behaviour, so it's not something you evaluate. In this context you can think of it as an error term telling you that $f(r)$ is roughly $1/4r$ with an additional contribution that is proportional to $\ln(r)/r^2$ as $r$ gets large (and therefore this contribution is negligible in comparison).

Comment: Well, if you have $\mathcal{O}(r^3)$ and you take a derivative with respect to $r$ the limiting term can be expected to transform to $\mathcal{O}(r^2)$.

Answer (score 4):

This symbol means that there's an error of aproximation, an example is the equation you mentioned:

$f(r) \sim \frac{1}{4r} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{ln(r)}{r^2})$

Here, the function $f(r)$ is being aproximated by the first term, it means that you can aproximate the actual value of the function $f(r)$ by computing the term $\frac{1}{4r}$, but by doing so, you'll have an error in the same order of magnitude as $\frac{ln(r)}{r^2}$. You can see that the expression for the error goes to zero as $r \to \infty$ meaning that the function $f(r)$ is better and better aproximated by $\frac{1}{4r}$ as $r$ increases.